# JMS transaction model with send and receive operations in Spring

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jms, activemq-classic

Consider the following rough example, where Spring is managing transactions as per a standard Spring Boot setup.

The default transaction manager provided by spring-boot-starter-data-jpa is used.

In this transactional unit of work, both database and JMS operations occur.

```
@Autowired JmsMessageOperations jmsMessageOperations;
@Autowired EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public void doWork() {
    entityManager.persist(new Foo(1));
    entityManager.flush();

    jmsMessageOperations.convertAndSend(BAR_QUEUE, new Bar(1));

    entityManager.persist(new Foo(2));
    entityManager.flush();

    BazResponse bazResponse = 
        jmsMessageOperations.convertSendAndReceive(
            BAZ_QUEUE, 
            new Baz(1), 
            BazResponse.class);

    // here    
}
```

What happens to these JMS messages (the two outbound and the one inbound), if at `// here` a:

- rollback exception is thrown,
- something (or nothing) occurs, resulting in committing the transaction.

I'm particularly interested in how the `convertSendAndReceive(...)` is managed, because obviously a response cannot be received until the send is committed - is the send of `Baz` handled in a different transaction to the send of `Bar`?

While I would expect the messaging implementation to not make a huge difference, I'm mostly interested in ActiveMQ.

Comment: Without knowing what you are using to manage the transactions this is impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've edited in reference to `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, which autoconfigures a transaction manager. If you were referring to the JMS side instead, I can also edit that information in.

Comment: If you don't use a transaction manager that spans both resources (i.e JTA based) then one part might commit and the other fails. You have 2 independent transactions.